# Classifying iPhone Apps by Language (English, Japanese,etc.)

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Does Apple provide a way for developers to classify the iPhone apps based on language? I have been checking out the various feeds and APIs provided by them, but there seems to be no way to pull apps from any particular language.

Kindly suggest if you know how to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find apps on the store that "support Japanese", you should check the feeds of the store in that region. Another trick that might work is using foreign-language keywords (only an app that supports french submits french keywords)

If you just want another languae - Most apps actually are multilingual. Just change your language setting on your device and every app supporting that lanuage will use it.

If you want to develop multilingual apps have a look at [Apple's Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i)

Comment: Thanks Martin. But this technique will only work if I already have a keyword to search. I am working on a script that will classify the apps based on the language that they support. For instance, the script should be able to tell that [this app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/gregg-young-chevrolet/id387705570) supports English, French, German, Italian and Spanish whereas [this one](http://itunes.apple.com/app/recgps/id406779092) supports only Japanese.